# Load BQ tables using python client libraries in Data Warehouse. Need Cost analysis. ETL vs ELT

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to develop a Data Warehouse that demands me to load JSON data into Big Query tables using Python. Columns are to be cast to certain datatypes as well. 
Which approach I should follow that would save me cost --

1)
a. load the data into Big Query table first by using Python Big Query client libraries in Staging tables.
b. Perform Cast SQLs on big query tables to update the schema. And Load into Data Warehousing tables.

2)
a. Perform Casts before loading the data into BQ tables. Use python libraries to either map datatypes or use Pandas dataframes to cast the data and use client libraries to Load cast data into BQ tables staging layer.
b. Merge staging tables to DW tables without any manipulations.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#streaming_pricing), loading data into BigQuery has no charge *per se* (unless you are [streaming data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)).

BigQuery gives you the option to use [schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect), but it deppends on your use case whether you think that is the better option or not. Using auto-detect might fail sometimes, as it is a best-effort tool (failing might be not inferring the correct type (job successful) or not being able to do so (job failed)).

I would recommend (if possible) setting schema locally (either manually or programatically) and then load the data.